# How do you add HTML headings dynamically in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, html

What is the server side control used to add an H4 to the markup from the code behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var h4 = new HtmlGenericControl("h4");
h4.InnerHtml = "Heading Text";
parentControl.Controls.Add(h4);
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend creating an `HtmlGenericControl` in your code-behind. The benefit of these over Literals is that they are proper HtmlControls, with the ability for you to programmatically set and modify properties such as `InnerHtml`, `CssClass`, `Style` etc.

```
HtmlGenericControl myH4 = new HtmlGenericControl("h4") 
{ 
   ID = "myH4",
   InnerHtml = "Your Heading Here" 
});
yourContainerControl.Controls.Add(myH4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `asp:Literal` control - this just writes out the exact text that you set it to.

E.g:

```
Dim myLiteral as Literal = new Literal()
myLiteral.Text = "<h4>My Heading</h4>"
```

Then add your Literal to the page.

Comment: I need it to be an H4 in the actual HTML source code, though, not just there.

Comment: It will write out an actual <h4> tag in the source as rendered to the browser.  Do you mean that you want the <h4> tag to be in your aspx code along with your other server tags?

Comment: In your aspx code have <asp:Literal runat="server" id="myLiteral" />
then like above use myLiteral.Text = "<h4>My Heading</h4>"; in the code behind

Comment: If you're going to use a `Literal`, it would still be better to leave the `<h4>` in the markup. So, have the markup as `<h4><asp:Literal ID="HeaderText" runat="server" /></h4>`.

Comment: I have an unknown number of h4 tags, though.

Comment: I think a `HtmlGenericControl` is preferable as it inherits from `HtmlControl`. `Literal` inherits from `Control` and is not as flexible.

Comment: In the process of answering a question I have become enlightened.  The teacher has become the learner.  I love that about StackOverflow.  Sounds like HtmlGenericControl is better than Literal then.  Go for that instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like a `<asp:H4 />` control.  However, you can add any HTML element to a page via [`HtmlGenericControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) type in your code behind.

For example, to create it:

```
HtmlGenericControl headerControl = new HtmlGenericControl(HtmlTextWriterTag.H4.ToString());
headerControl.ID = "myHeader";
headerControl.InnerHtml = "Hello World";
placeHolder.Controls.Add(headerControl);
```

To access it from code behind later:

```
HtmlGenericControl headerControl = FindControl("myHeader") as HtmlGenericControl;
```

Comment: If you give an `id` and a `runat="server"` to an element, it should just be another property of the page object, just like a normal ASP.Net control (e.g. Label). So instead of using `FindControl`, you can just do `this.myHeader`.

Comment: Unfortunately the question was how to add *dynamically*.